# Mysql Concat is displaying byte array

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I am new at mysql. I have code but it is displaying byte array why ? 
Sorry about my english :(

```
SELECT p.city_id,p.name city, CONCAT("[", 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{id:"', a.id, '", address:"', a.address, '"}')), 
"]") As sahalar 
FROM cities AS p LEFT JOIN carpet_fields As a ON(p.city_id = a.city_id) 
GROUP BY p.city_id, p.name ORDER BY p.city_id
```

it must be show json data but. The result is

Wrong result

```
 city_id  name   sahalar
1        ADANA  0x5B7B69643A223236222C20616464726573733A2248757A75
```

Correct result

```
city_id name sahalar 
1       ADANA [{id:"1A", address:"Huzurevleri Mah.77232 Sk. ADANA / ÇUKUROVA"},{id:"1B", address:"KARSLILAR MAH. 82008. SOK. / MAHFESIGMAZ"}]
```

[image: hata]

Comment: Try converting numbers to strings before concatenating (or deploy a conversion to string within the `CONCAT` function, e.g. applying it to `a.id`).

Comment: this time it gives me cast error. you can click this link to see the error
http://i.hizliresim.com/X6DP36.png

Comment: Out NW security prevents accessing the link you posted. Still, I see that `id` is also a string... (and hence no need to cast). Where do you see the wrong JSON? Can you print it within the DB?

Comment: In database. heidi my sql query

Comment: i have added image but it's not displaying

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; 
SELECT p.city_id,p.name city, 
CONCAT("[", 
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('{id:"', CAST(a.id as char(10)), '", address:"', a.address, '"}') ), 
"]") As sahalar 
FROM cities AS p 
LEFT JOIN carpet_fields As a ON(p.city_id = a.city_id)  
GROUP BY p.city_id, p.name ORDER BY p.city_id
```